# Run multiple task load from database using windows service

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I created windows service and run using timers work expected for single task. But what I need is to run multiple task loaded from database contains all the details for timers(Schedule). I don’t know how to manage it and perform tasks using single timer or multiple timer.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you want [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/).

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for the reply. I will check about Quartz. Can we create the same with Task Scheduler to run multiple task having all the schedule details saved in database in C#?

Comment: I want to perform multiple task at predefined scheduled for each task using windows service. How could I?